# The best choice database (millions files - most less than 100 mb)

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, database

What the best choice to use in my case? ANy suggestion? I have millions of file (70 millions today) - (most less than 100mb), but I need to use a databse for indexes and store this file.

Unfortunally I tried to use the HDFS unsucessfull. Any suggestions of database for this?

Regards